# How to release the microphone from the Connectycube conference session

Tags: webrtc, microphone, connectycube

The ConnectyCube.videochatconference.createNewSession() attaches both video and audio from the device camera and microphone.  Now, I need the session to release the microphone so that another process, which is a speech to text API that is not running in the browser, can use it.  I know while the microphone is being used, other remote participants will not hear any audio from this participant. After the other process is done, I need to reattach the microphone to the session so that other participants will again hear audio from this participant.

The videoconference session exposes a stream property. I tried to get a new stream from the media devices (only video from the camera but no audio) by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. I was hoping this would release the microphone.  I then assigned the new stream to the stream property of the session for the user.  However microphone could not be released so no other process on the device (an Android mobile phone) could access it. I also tried session.muteAudio() but this would also not release the microphone.